# Laravel unique user profile url like facebook

Tags: laravel

Assume I have a site with a unique URL for users, e.g. **abc.com/user1**.
I want users to be able to create their own user urls like abc.com/user1 to abc.com/foo

The problem here is that my site has static pages such as: about, help, contact, download.

On the profile page, when users change their url, i apply this validator to their new profile url:

```
'username'      => 'required|alpha_dash|max:20|min:3|unique:users'
```

In this situation, if the user chooses their new profile url to the same as a Route of my app (help, about, download...), their URL looks like: **abc.com/about**, this is troublesome.
Of course, the Validator will return ***true*** because that name is valid: min=3, max=20 and unique in **"users"** table ( **"users"** table not contains any control, of course).

To solve this, I add name of some Route to "users" table (about,contact,download...), so they cannot make their profile URL like abc.com/about,
But this is not good idea, because I might add more Routes in future.

PS: I dont like URL like **abc.com/profile/user1**, must be ***abc.com/user1***.
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Route::getRoutes()` to get all registered routes in your application

```
$routes = Route::getRoutes();
foreach($routes as $route){
    echo $route->getUri(); // getUri will return the url pattern it matches
}
```

Now you can use this to check if the username doesn't appear in your routes.

But **be careful!** If you want to add routes in when the application is running you will have to check everytime that there's no user that has taken the name you want to chose.

Comment: So Route for user URL must after other Route like about,help...?

Comment: Yes, since it will be a "catch-all" route `Route::get('{user}')` and will match every other request. So you have to define all the other routes first

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibilities

#### 1. Call static page routes first

You can either call the static routes first and then at the end you do a catchall like lukasgeiter suggested, or you might even do a check in the controller and go through your static pages first. The problem here is that the user can create the user (e.g. "about") but then when they call that page, they would see the about page, even though they've correctly created the username, this might create a confusion.

#### 2. Blacklist

Another way would be to create a blacklist for these usernames, so that people can't even register these types of usernames (this would be similar to your solution of pre-creating those usernames, but this way would be a bit cleaner and more easily expandable). Using this you will always have the trouble that someone will have used the username, once you want to use it as a static page. E.g. when you want to expand into another country.

#### 3. Static pages on one level lower

E.g. you can create the static pages one level lower, such as abc.com/static/about, so there would be no clash.

#### 4. Prepend character before username

This is the way I went, because the other ways were technically a bit too risky for me. So I chose the '@' sign for my users. So abc.com/@ThisIsMe is my current solution. It works in different languages (as opposed to abc.com/profile/thisisme would only work in languages, where profile is the correct term)

I think Flickr went from flickr.com/username to flickr.com/photos/username. Google+ doesn't really let you decide, but makes suggestions (AND adds the +). Twitter and Facebook let users choose their own, I would assume they have a blacklist. LinkedIn uses /in/.

Comment: Regarding the problem you mention in #1. My answer is entirely about how to validate the username so they can't create one that exists as route.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then it's more of a mix of #1 and #2. In my answer, #1 would only check AFTER the username is created, #2 would check BEFORE the username is created.